# US tax liability of F1 student working abroad as a contractor for US company

Tags: taxes

I am an F1 student working for a US company from abroad (Ukraine) during summer. I am wondering then what sort of taxes should I pay given this? I know there are some tax treaties preventing from double taxation and I guess I am generally trying to figure out if I should even be paying US taxes at all if I wont be present in the US? My employer is thinking of issuing 1099 form for me in the end. Any help will be appreciated a lot!

I did pay taxes to the US in the past so I do have SSN and am a US tax payer.

Answer (score 2):

If you were a nonresident alien (which is usually the case for the first 5 calendar years of F1 status), and you performed the work while in Ukraine, you should not be subject to any US tax on that income. I don't think the company needs to issue you a 1099, since you are essentially a foreign contractor working in a foreign country. You would still be responsible for reporting your income to Ukrainian tax authorities and paying any Ukrainian income and self-employment taxes.